# Boost asio blocking operations in a std::thread instead of using async methods?

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

So I've been struggling with creating some abstraction layer over Boost.Asio. There are certain batches of operations I want to treat atomically, for example `tcp::resolver::resolve()` and `asio::connect()`. If I use the async version of both of these, the code gets real nasty because I have to "chain" the callbacks. Essentially:

1. User calls my `Connect()` wrapper method, which takes a host and a service string, and they also provide a callback that is invoked when the connection is done.
2. Invoke `resolver::async_resolve()` using the host and service string parameters. Bind the user's callback to the callback for resolve (to pass along the callback to be invoked after connecting)
3. From resolve callback, if successful, invoke `asio::async_connect()`. Again, bind the user's callback to the connect callback.
4. In the connect callback, if successful, invoke the user's callback

Either this is nasty because of a ton of nested lambdas, or nasty because the functions are separated and now I have a class loaded with boilerplate. Seems to me it would be much simpler to just do something like this (didn't compile, so just treat this as pseudo-code for now):

```
   using ConnectCallback = std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>)>;

   void Connect(std::string const& host, std::string const& service, ConnectCallback cb)
   {
      std::thread{[this, host, service, cb{std::move(cb)}]
      {
         std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket;

         try
         {
            tcp::resolver r{m_context};
            auto endpoints = r.resolve(host, service);

            socket = std::make_shared<tcp::socket>(m_context);
            asio::connect(*socket, endpoints);
         }
         catch (std::exception const&)
         {
            // either resolve or connect failed / timed out
         }

         cb(std::move(socket));
      }}.detach();
   }
```

To me this is much simpler, at least for initiating the connection, because I don't have to worry about so many callbacks. The only downside is that I am not sure how to handle timeout scenarios using this method. All solutions related to timeouts I've found on Google require the usage of the `async_` methods.

Is it recommended to do things this way, or do I have to stick with the async methods? And if the latter, what techniques can I use to simplify the callback chaining boilerplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If writing handlers is annoying for you, you may consider using [coroutines](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/spawn.html). It works with asynchronous operations and enable you to implement timeout.

```
struct Client2 {
    Client2(asio::io_context& io)
    : io(io) {}

    asio::io_context& io;
    asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver{io};
    asio::ip::tcp::socket sock{io};
    asio::high_resolution_timer timer{io};
    atomic_bool stopped{false};

    void connect (const string& host, const string& service, int timeoutMs)
    {
        boost::asio::spawn(io,std::bind(&Client2::establishConnection,this,host,service,timeoutMs,std::placeholders::_1));
        boost::asio::spawn(io,std::bind(&Client2::doTimeout,this,std::placeholders::_1));
    }
    void establishConnection (string host, string service, int timeoutMs,boost::asio::yield_context yield)
    {
        try {
            timer.expires_after(std::chrono::milliseconds(timeoutMs)); // set timeout
            auto res = resolver.async_resolve(host,service,yield); 
            // resume here when handler for resolving was called
            if (stopped)
                return;
            asio::async_connect(sock,res,yield);
            timer.cancel(); // connection is established, do sth with sock here, cancel timer
        }
        catch (std::exception& ex) {
        }
    }
    void doTimeout (boost::asio::yield_context yield)
    {
        try {
            timer.async_wait(yield); // throw exception when was canceled by startConnecting
        }
        catch (std::exception& ex) {
            return;
        }
        resolver.cancel(); // timeout == timer expired, so cancel resolving and close socket
        sock.close();
        stopped = true;
    }
};

// in main
        asio::io_context io;
        Client2 client{io};
        client.connect("localhost","5444",200);
        thread th([&](){ io.run(); }); // call run from at least 2 threads
        io.run();  // establishConnection and doTimeout can be executed concurrently
        th.join();
```

I have added some comments in the code.
In short: Two coroutines are used. In `establishConnection` two async operations are executed: `async_resolve` and `async_connect`. In `doTimeout` coroutine `timer` is started. When timer expires before a connection is established, we cancel resolving and close socket. If a connection was established before the timer is expired, we cancel the timer and we can perform some operations with `sock`.

The bodies of `establishConnection` and `doTimeout` can be moved into lambda, as argument of `asio::spawn` function. So we could have only one member function, and no handlers for the code where 3 async operations are performed. If this satisfies you, start using coroutines.

Comment: This definitely looks like a huge improvement. Is `yield` basically doing a thread sleep until the corresponding callback for that `async_*` function is invoked?

Comment: @void.pointer When *async_operation* is called with `yield` in coroutine function, coroutine is suspended, and `io_context::run` may process other tasks, i.e. call some handlers, process another coroutine etc. When the callback for *async_operation* is completed, coroutine is resumed and the execution is continued from the last async operation. *thread sleep* means that the execution hangs in coroutine, what is not true. When coroutine is suspended by calling `async + yield`, the execution context is changed, and we enter back into coroutine when callback is completed.